# Issues with Java Validation method

Tags: java, validation, methods

**EDIT:  THE CODE HAS BEEN UPDATED TO THE CORRECT FORMAT.  THANK YOU TO EVERYONE WHO HELPED ME SOLVE THIS.**

Thanks for taking a look at this question.  I'm in a Java Programming class at Community College and my professor uploaded a .pdf document of a java program for us to copy and input into an IDE.  She literally just wanted us to type it into the IDE ourselves and turn it in for 5 points extra credit on our midterm.

The problem is, I found a couple of problems with her code that wont allow it to run (or maybe I'm just not aware of how its used properly.  I'm not trying to seem pompous).

There is a line of code in the program that wants to validate the carType of the program.  It is as follows:

```
         carType = validateCarType(carType);
```

When I try to run the program, it says:

```
CarWash.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
```

I typed it in myself the first time and thought maybe I typed it wrong, then I copy/pasted from the PDF document.  No luck.

How would that command be used?  Should I be declaring something?  If you could show me how its used and include an explanation, I'd greatly appreciate it.  I'm currently working on a side project with the stuff I learn from Java that will calculate the taxes I need to save up from my 1099 independent contracting job and I want to understand this in case I need to use it.

I did check my textbook and I didn't see that kind of validation method anywhere.  They were mostly while and for loops.

Much appreciated!

the following is the entire code:

**EDIT:  The following code is now working thanks to fellow Community Members helping me solve this.  The below code is UPDATED**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CarWash
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String name = " ";
  String runProgram = " ";
  int washType = 0;
  char carType = ' ';
  char extras = ' ';
  double basicPrice = 0.0;
  double adder = 0.0;
  double extraPrice = 0.0;
  double totalPrice = 0.0;
  final double SHINE_PRICE = 4.95;
  final double MAT_PRICE = 8.95;
  final double CWAX = 7.95;

  System.out.println("Welcome to the Car Wsh");
  System.out.println("Enter Yes to start the program or No to quit.");
  runProgram = keyboard.nextLine();
  runProgram = runProgram.toLowerCase();

  while (runProgram.equals("yes"))
  {

     //Getting user input
     System.out.println("Please enter your name");
     name = keyboard.nextLine();

     System.out.println("Please choose the type of car wash:");
     System.out.println("1.  Pleasant Colony - sedan $34.95 SUV $35.95");
     System.out.println("2.  Secretariat - sedan $24.95 SUV $25.95");
     System.out.println("3.  Gallant Fox - sedan $19.95 SUV $20.95");
     System.out.println("4.  Pony Express - sedan $14.95 SUV $15.95");
     System.out.println("5.  Win - $12.95");
     System.out.println("6.  Show - $8.95");
     washType = keyboard.nextInt();
     keyboard.nextLine();

     //Input validation loop for washType

     while (washType < 1 || washType > 6) //this works
     //while (washType != 1 && washType !=2 && washType !=3 && washType !=4 && washType !=5 && washType != 6)//This works
     {

        System.out.println("Invalid data.");
        System.out.println("Please enter a value from 1 to 6.");
        washType = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

     }//end washType while

     System.out.println("Please enter a S for Sedan or V for SUV.");
     carType = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
     carType = Character.toUpperCase(carType);

     //validation method for carType
     carType = validateCarType(carType);

     //The above code did not work at all.  I had to create my own validator for this.

     //below presents 2 different menus to the user for extras
     if (washType == 1 || washType == 2)
     {

        System.out.println("Please choose the extras:");
        System.out.println("A.  No Extras $0.00");
        System.out.println("B.  Mat Shampoo $8.95");
        System.out.println("C.  Carnauba Wax $7.95");
        System.out.println("D.  Both Mat Shampoo and Carnauba Wax $16.90"); //On the BB document, you put E, so I changed it to D

     }//end washType if

     else
     {

        System.out.println("Please choose the extras:");
        System.out.println("A.  No Extras $0.00");
        System.out.println("B.  Mat Shampoo $8.95");
        System.out.println("C.  Carnauba Wax $7.95");
        System.out.println("D.  Tire Shine $4.95");
        System.out.println("E.  Both Mat Shampoo and Carnauba Wax $16.90");
        System.out.println("F.  Both Mat Shampoo and tire Shine $13.90");
        System.out.println("G.  Both Carnauba Wax and Tire Shine $12.90");
        System.out.println("H.  All: Mat Shampoo and Carnauba Wax and Tire Shine $21.85");

     }//end else

     extras = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
     extras = Character.toUpperCase(extras);

     //Validation loop for extras

     while (extras != 'A' && extras != 'B' && extras != 'C' && extras != 'D' && extras != 'E' && extras != 'F' && extras != 'G' && extras != 'H') //This works
     {

        System.out.println("Invalid data.");
        System.out.println("Please enter either A, B, C, D, E, F, G, or H.");
        extras = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
        extras = Character.toUpperCase(extras);

     }//end Invalid extras while

     //determines basicPrice based on washType
     basicPrice = setBasicPrice(washType);

     //determines adder based on carType
     adder = setAdderPrice(carType);

     //determines extraPrice based on extras
     switch (extras)
     {

        case 'A':
           extraPrice = 0.0;
           break;
        case 'B':
           extraPrice = MAT_PRICE; //extraPrice = 8.95;
           break;
        case 'C':
           extraPrice = CWAX; //extraPrice = 7.95;
           break;
        case 'D':
           extraPrice = SHINE_PRICE;
           break;
        case 'E':
           extraPrice = 16.90;
           break;
        case 'F':
           extraPrice = 13.90;
           break;
        case 'G':
           extraPrice = 12.90;
           break;
        case 'H':
           extraPrice = 21.85;
           break;
        default:
           extraPrice = 0.0;
           break;

     }//end extras switch

     //method to calculate totalPrice
     totalPrice = calcTotalPrice(basicPrice, adder, extraPrice);

     //method to print a horizontal line of characters
     printLineOfChars('*', 60);

     //method to display results
     displayResults(name, washType, carType, basicPrice, adder, extraPrice, totalPrice);

     //method to print a horizontal line of characters
     printLineOfChars('*', 60);

     //give the user a chance to run the program again or quit
     System.out.println("Please enter Yes to run the program again or No to quit.");
     runProgram = keyboard.nextLine();
     runProgram = runProgram.toLowerCase();

  }//end runProgram while

  System.out.println("Thanks for using the Car Wash Program.");

}//end main

//calctotalPrice method calculates the total price
public static double calcTotalPrice(double myBasicPrice, double myAdder, double myExtraPrice)
{
  double myTotalPrice = 0.0;

  myTotalPrice = myBasicPrice + myAdder + myExtraPrice;

  return myTotalPrice;

}//end double calcTotalPrice() method

//printLineOfChars method prints a horizozntal line of chars
public static void printLineOfChars(char myCharacter, int myLoopCounter)
{

  for (int i = 0; i <= myLoopCounter; i++)
  {

     System.out.print(myCharacter);

  }//end for

  System.out.println();

}//end printLineOfChars()

//validateCarType method validates the car type as either S or V
public static char validateCarType(char myCarType) 
{

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  while (myCarType != 'S' && myCarType != 'V')
  {

     System.out.println("Invalid data.");
     System.out.println("Please enter S for Sedan or V for SUV");
     myCarType = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
     myCarType = Character.toUpperCase(myCarType);

  }

  return myCarType;

}//end of validateCarType

public static void displayResults(String myName, int myWashType, char myCarType, double myBasicPrice, double myAdder, double myExtraPrice, double myTotalPrice)
{ 

  //display results
  System.out.printf("%-35s%10s\n", "Customer Name", myName);
  System.out.printf("%-35s%10s\n", "Car Wash Chosen", myWashType);
  System.out.printf("%-35s%10s\n", "Car Type", myCarType);
  System.out.printf("%-35s%10.2f\n", "Basic Price: ", myBasicPrice);
  System.out.printf("%-35s%10.2f\n", "Adder: ", myAdder);
  System.out.printf("%-35s%10.2f\n", "Extras: ", myExtraPrice);
  System.out.printf("%-35s%10.2f\n", "Total Price: ", myTotalPrice);

}//end displayresults() method

//setAdderPrice method calculates the adder
public static double setAdderPrice(char myCarType)
{

  double myAdder = 0.0;
  if (myCarType == 'S')
  {

     myAdder = 0.00;

  }//end if

  else
  {

     myAdder = 1.00;

  }//end else

  return myAdder;

}//end setAdderPrice() method

//setBasicPrice method sets the basic price based on washType
public static double setBasicPrice(int myWashType)
{

  double myBasicPrice = 0.0;
  switch (myWashType)
  {

     case 1:
        myBasicPrice = 34.95;
        break;
     case 2:
        myBasicPrice = 24.95;
        break;
     case 3:
        myBasicPrice = 19.95;
        break;
     case 4:
        myBasicPrice = 14.95;
        break;
     case 5:
        myBasicPrice = 12.95;
        break;
     case 6:
        myBasicPrice = 8.95;
        break;
     default:
        myBasicPrice = 0.0;

  }//end Swtich (myWashType)

  return myBasicPrice;

}//end setBasicPrice() method

}//end class
```

Comment: You'd need to have a method in your class with the following signature to make this work: `static char validateCarType(char carType) { ... }` where "..." is the code that you need to write that does the validation.

Comment: I can't see validateCarType(carType); method in your class
that's why you are getting CarWash.java:69: error: cannot find symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add validateCarType method in your class. There is no method is defined in your class. put this method in your class.

```
 private static char validateCarType(char carType) {
    //here is your code
    return '0';
  }
```

there are some spelling mistakes. change

```
double extraPricec = 0.0;
```

to

```
double extraPrice = 0.0;
```

and add a break after 'G' case.

```
case 'G':
           extraPrice = 12.90;
           break;// that was missing
```

and when you are calling function spellings again wrong
change

```
printLineofChars('*', 60);//O is in uppercase
```

to

```
printLineOfChars('*', 60);
```

The code below is perfectly fine working in my IDE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarWash {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = " ";
    String runProgram = " ";
    int washType = 0;
    char carType = ' ';
    char extras = ' ';
    double basicPrice = 0.0;
    double adder = 0.0;
    double extraPrice = 0.0;
    double totalPrice = 0.0;
    final double SHINE_PRICE = 4.95;
    final double MAT_PRICE = 8.95;
    final double CWAX = 7.95;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Car Wsh");
    System.out.println("Enter Yes to start the program or No to quit.");
    runProgram = keyboard.nextLine();
    runProgram = runProgram.toLowerCase();

    while (runProgram.equals("yes"))
    {

      //Getting user input
      System.out.println("Please enter your name");
      name = keyboard.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Please choose the type of car wash:");
      System.out.println("1.  Pleasant Colony - sedan $34.95 SUV $35.95");
      System.out.println("2.  Secretariat - sedan $24.95 SUV $25.95");
      System.out.println("3.  Gallant Fox - sedan $19.95 SUV $20.95");
      System.out.println("4.  Pony Express - sedan $14.95 SUV $15.95");
      System.out.println("5.  Win - $12.95");
      System.out.println("6.  Show - $8.95");
      washType = keyboard.nextInt();
      keyboard.nextLine();

      //Input validation loop for washType

      while (washType < 1 || washType > 6) //this works
      //while (washType != 1 && washType !=2 && washType !=3 && washType !=4 && washType !=5 && washType != 6)//This works
      {

        System.out.println("Invalid data.");
        System.out.println("Please enter a value from 1 to 6.");
        washType = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

      }//end washType while

      System.out.println("Please enter a S for Sedan or V for SUV.");
      carType = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
      carType = Character.toUpperCase(carType);

      //validation method for carType
      validateCarType(carType);

      //below presents 2 different menus to the user for extras
      if (washType == 1 || washType == 2)
      {

        System.out.println("Please choose the extras:");
        System.out.println("A.  No Extras $0.00");
        System.out.println("B.  Mat Shampoo $8.95");
        System.out.println("C.  Carnauba Wax $7.95");
        System.out.println("D.  Both Mat Shampoo and Carnauba Wax $16.90"); //On the BB document, you put E, so I changed it to D

      }//end washType if

      else
      {

        System.out.println("Please choose the extras:");
        System.out.println("A.  No Extras $0.00");
        System.out.println("B.  Mat Shampoo $8.95");
        System.out.println("C.  Carnauba Wax $7.95");
        System.out.println("D.  Tire Shine $4.95");
        System.out.println("E.  Both Mat Shampoo and Carnauba Wax $16.90");
        System.out.println("F.  Both Mat Shampoo and tire Shine $13.90");
        System.out.println("G.  Both Carnauba Wax and Tire Shine $12.90");
        System.out.println("H.  All: Mat Shampoo and Carnauba Wax and Tire Shine $21.85");

      }//end else

      extras = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
      extras = Character.toUpperCase(extras);

      //Validation loop for extras

      while (extras != 'A' && extras != 'B' && extras != 'C' && extras != 'D' && extras != 'E' && extras != 'F' && extras != 'G' && extras != 'H') //This works
      {

        System.out.println("Invalid data.");
        System.out.println("Please enter either A, B, C, D, E, F, G, or H.");
        extras = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
        extras = Character.toUpperCase(extras);

      }//end Invalid extras while

      //determines basicPrice based on washType
      basicPrice = setBasicPrice(washType);

      //determines adder based on carType
      adder = setAdderPrice(carType);

      //determines extraPrice based on extras
      switch (extras)
      {

        case 'A':
          extraPrice = 0.0;
          break;
        case 'B':
          extraPrice = MAT_PRICE; //extraPrice = 8.95;
          break;
        case 'C':
          extraPrice = CWAX; //extraPrice = 7.95;
          break;
        case 'D':
          extraPrice = SHINE_PRICE;
          break;
        case 'E':
          extraPrice = 16.90;
          break;
        case 'F':
          extraPrice = 13.90;
          break;
        case 'G':
          extraPrice = 12.90;
        case 'H':
          extraPrice = 21.85;
          break;
        default:
          extraPrice = 0.0;
          break;

      }//end extras switch

      //method to calculate totalPrice
      totalPrice = calcTotalPrice(basicPrice, adder, extraPrice);

      //method to print a horizontal line of characters
      printLineOfChars('*', 60);

      //method to display results
      displayResults(name, washType, carType, basicPrice, adder, extraPrice, totalPrice);

      //method to print a horizontal line of characters
      printLineOfChars('*', 60);

      //give the user a chance to run the program again or quit
      System.out.println("Please enter Yes to run the program again or No to quit.");
      runProgram = keyboard.nextLine();
      runProgram = runProgram.toLowerCase();

    }//end runProgram while

    System.out.println("Thanks for using the Car Wash Program.");

  }//end main

  private static void validateCarType(char carType) {
  }

  //calctotalPrice method calculates the total price
  public static double calcTotalPrice(double myBasicPrice, double myAdder, double myExtraPrice)
  {
    double myTotalPrice = 0.0;

    myTotalPrice = myBasicPrice + myAdder + myExtraPrice;

    return myTotalPrice;

  }//end double calcTotalPrice() method

  //printLineOfChars method prints a horizozntal line of chars
  public static void printLineOfChars(char myCharacter, int myLoopCounter)
  {

    for (int i = 0; i <= myLoopCounter; i++)
    {

      System.out.print(myCharacter);

    }//end for

    System.out.println();

  }//end printLineOfChars()

  public static void displayResults(String myName, int myWashType, char myCarType, double myBasicPrice, double myAdder, double myExtraPrice, double myTotalPrice)
  {

    //display results
    System.out.printf("%-35s%10s\n", "Customer Name", myName);
    System.out.printf("%-35s%10s\n", "Car Wash Chosen", myWashType);
    System.out.printf("%-35s%10s\n", "Car Type", myCarType);
    System.out.printf("%-35s%10.2f\n", "Basic Price: ", myBasicPrice);
    System.out.printf("%-35s%10.2f\n", "Adder: ", myAdder);
    System.out.printf("%-35s%10.2f\n", "Extras: ", myExtraPrice);
    System.out.printf("%-35s%10.2f\n", "Total Price: ", myTotalPrice);

  }//end displayresults() method

  //setAdderPrice method calculates the adder
  public static double setAdderPrice(char myCarType)
  {

    double myAdder = 0.0;
    if (myCarType == 'S')
    {

      myAdder = 0.00;

    }//end if

    else
    {

      myAdder = 1.00;

    }//end else

    return myAdder;

  }//end setAdderPrice() method

  //setBasicPrice method sets the basic price based on washType
  public static double setBasicPrice(int myWashType)
  {

    double myBasicPrice = 0.0;
    switch (myWashType)
    {

      case 1:
        myBasicPrice = 34.95;
        break;
      case 2:
        myBasicPrice = 24.95;
        break;
      case 3:
        myBasicPrice = 19.95;
        break;
      case 4:
        myBasicPrice = 14.95;
        break;
      case 5:
        myBasicPrice = 12.95;
        break;
      case 6:
        myBasicPrice = 8.95;
        break;
      default:
        myBasicPrice = 0.0;

    }//end Swtich (myWashType)

    return myBasicPrice;

  }//end setBasicPrice() method

}
```

and it is the output when i run this program :

```
Welcome to the Car Wsh
Enter Yes to start the program or No to quit.
yes
Please enter your name
khalid
Please choose the type of car wash:
1.  Pleasant Colony - sedan $34.95 SUV $35.95
2.  Secretariat - sedan $24.95 SUV $25.95
3.  Gallant Fox - sedan $19.95 SUV $20.95
4.  Pony Express - sedan $14.95 SUV $15.95
5.  Win - $12.95
6.  Show - $8.95
1
Please enter a S for Sedan or V for SUV.
S
Please choose the extras:
A.  No Extras $0.00
B.  Mat Shampoo $8.95
C.  Carnauba Wax $7.95
D.  Both Mat Shampoo and Carnauba Wax $16.90
A
*************************************************************
Customer Name                          khalid
Car Wash Chosen                             1
Car Type                                    S
Basic Price:                            34.95
Adder:                                   0.00
Extras:                                  0.00
Total Price:                            34.95
*************************************************************
Please enter Yes to run the program again or No to quit.
```

Comment: Hi Khalid, I tried to use the private static char but it messes up my code pretty bad.  Gives me .java:65: error: illegal start of expression

Comment: carType = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

Comment: Khalid, 
Your help worked!  I realized what I was doing wrong.  I kept putting the validation method at the bottom of the code because I got confused with the brackets.  I appreciate your help!  You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the method is missing from the source code. If I had to guess, the intent for that method is that it should mimic the preceding while loop that repeatedly asks for the washType until a valid value is entered.

You could implement the method yourself, as some others have already suggested, under the above assumption, or you could just comment out that line, and it should still run. The carType variable is passed to the setAdderPrice method, which will default to the value for SUV if it's passed an invalid type.

**EDIT:**
I see you already updated the method signature to have a return type of char and got your loop working. The only additional suggestion I would make is to pass your existing Scanner to the function instead of creating a new one.

```
//validation method for carType
 carType = validateCarType(carType, keyboard);
```

and

```
//validateCarType method validates the car type as either S or V
public static char validateCarType(char myCarType, Scanner scanner) 
{

  while (myCarType != 'S' && myCarType != 'V')
  {

     System.out.println("Invalid data.");
     System.out.println("Please enter S for Sedan or V for SUV");
     myCarType = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
     myCarType = Character.toUpperCase(myCarType);

  }

  return myCarType;

}//end of validateCarType
```

Comment: Hi Tony,  
You're right, it is to mimic the prior one.  I attempted to copy/paste the prior validation loop, but after 2 times, it automatically moves on to the next step in the process.  Any ideas on how to fix that?